# Arduino Array - Defining, adding and looping

Tags: arrays, arduino

Super noob question but I am having a hard time understanding arrays in Arduino. I have done a bunch of reading and fiddling but I think I am missing some core ideas. I have three questions below...  as comments in my code.

```cpp
//Question1: Is there anyway to keep this a dynamic array length?
int arrname[20];

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

    //Question 2: How can I add this to the end of the array?
    arrname[0] = data from sensor;

    int arrsize = sizeof(arrname) / sizeof(arrname[0]);

    //Question 3: Why is this not iterating through the values?
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(valarr); i=i+1){ 
        Serial.print(valarr[i]);
    }

}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Q3 - you never set `valarr`

Comment: and putting arghh in your title is not helpful, you should consider editing it, even potentially putting your 3 questions into separate questions with appropriate titles that make sense...

Comment: Alright title edited... and I purposely put it into one question as I feel there is an overall idea I am missing....

Comment: I think this resource will help you to get further and see some of the differences between JS and Arduino code and working with arrays: http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Array

Comment: much improved title! I +1 you for your effort :D

Comment: This may also help you to get your head around trying to dynamicize arrays in arduino: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=42373.0

Comment: The thing to keep in mind is that arrays are not like in JS where you can just shove things into and remove items and everything is great...They have a fixed length on initialization.